# onclick return two functions (Tracking)

Tags: javascript, onclick, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to trigger two functions on the onclick event. They are used for tracking link from website. One is for GoogletagManager, the other one is for AdForm tracking.

I get error that the function is not defined. Any solutions to make this work?

```
<a href="https://www.example.com" target="_blank" onclick="myFunction();">Link</a>

  <script type="text/javascript">

  function myFunction(){
      secondone();
      firstone();
  }
  function firstone() {
      return console.log('first');
      return gtag_report_conversion1('http://www.example.com');
  }
  function secondone() {
      return console.log('second');
      return window.adf&&adf.ClickTrack ( this,{123456},'Page Name',{});
  }

  </script>
  <script>
function gtag_report_conversion1(url) {
  var callback = function () {
    if (typeof(url) != 'undefined') {
      window.location = url;
    }
  };
  gtag('event', 'conversion', {
      'send_to': 'AW-465465465465465',
      'event_callback': callback
  });
  return false;
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
      window._adftrack = Array.isArray(window._adftrack) ? window._adftrack : (window._adftrack ? [window._adftrack] : []);
      window._adftrack.push({
          pm: 123456,
          divider: encodeURIComponent('|'),
          pagename: encodeURIComponent('Page Name')
      });
      (function () { var s = document.createElement('script'); s.type = 'text/javascript'; s.async = true; s.src = 'https://track.adform.net/serving/scripts/trackpoint/async/'; var x = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x); })();

  </script>
```

Comment: Where are you declaring your functions? Are they in a <script> tag? Or are they in the .js file that is included on the page? Could you please post more code or create a JSFiddle demo? And which function specifically is not defined?

Comment: I doubt that gtag_report_conversion1 or adf.ClickTrack are called in your code anyways.

Comment: Which is the function error reporting not defined? myFunction / first / second?

Comment: @Joschi They are called, look at the edited question

Comment: @Sachink ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined. If i remove the return the second returns from Gtag and Adform and just leave the console.log then it works...

Comment: @AnnaPohorielova Hi, eveything is in the html file, wrapped in scripts tags, check the edited question if it helps you.

Comment: I see. Why do you do ``return window.adf&&adf.ClickTrack( this,{123456},'Page Name',{});`` from  second function and ``return gtag_report_conversion1('http://www.example.com');`` from the first one? Why not just calling them in place? You are not using their results in myFunction anyway.

Comment: @AnnaPohorielova That's how the events are defined in official documentation, Should I call both return in just one function?

Comment: @unforgiven the error starts to appear when you call ``window.adf.ClickTrack``. When I remove all params except ``this`` from this function call, ``myFunction`` stops breaking. Please, check the library docs again and see if you are passing the correct parameters. I suspect that the call to ``ClickTrack`` function might be overwriting ``window`` properties or something. And probably that is why ``myFunction`` is not found.

Comment: @unforgiven You have a syntax error in secondone(), change `{123456}` to `"123456"`and see if your problem still exists

Comment: @Joschi Hey thanks! it's working, but I've another problem, when i click the link, it has to open it in new tab. It opens it in new tab, but the current active tab goes to the permalink site, if I comment the window.location(url);  in the code it works fine, but this line is important for sending data to GA.

Comment: @Joschi Fixed the problem, the problem was, one function was actually not written right so it broke the code and didn't work like it should.

Answer (score 0):

After reading your edit - try moving all of the functions to the same `<script></script>` tag :)

Comment: That's likely not the problem.  `<script>` tags do not affect scope.